# IS RadeonDriver support for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, upgrade, graphics, 16.04, amd-graphics

I am a Amd user of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. After referring some sites, I found that Ubuntu 16.04 LTS doesn't have drivers which will support RadeonDriver.

According to these sites AMD users had to wait for a while. Can you please tell me for what time should I wait to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? Can you please tell me the waiting time?

This is my amd driver

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8650G] [1002:990b]
```

Do I have any support at present?

Comment: All duplicates do not answer the question asked here. It is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

No. There's currently no fglrx or because the latest Ubuntu release dropped amd's propietary drivers support.

Also, if you have an APU (Accelerated Processor Unit), those AMD's apus with Turbocore you must stay away from installing Ubuntu 16.04. The actual drivers don't support boost processor states so your proc's performance will be limited to its common limits with the open source drivers.
TL;DR: Don't install Ubuntu 16.04. If you want to use Linux, then go with nvidia and intel.